# Is there a way to get directory part from variable in make?

Tags: linux, make, c++

I have makefile, where I define some lib and its path:

```
MY_LIB= dir/lib
```

Now I know that I can use @D to get directory part from target:

```
#This will go to dir
$(MY_LIB):
    cd $(@D)
```

But I want to use the directory part of MY_LIB in other target:

```
$(TARGET):
    doSomething $(INSERT_MY_LIB_DIR_HERE)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the `$(basename $path)` for filename and `$(dir $path)` for dir component

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, very likely you are using GNU make.  That has a [`dir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) function.  So you could have a rule like

```
$(TARGET):
    doSomething $(dir $(MY_LIB))
```

(Not found in [POSIX make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)—other implementations may have similar extensions).